# New action not being reached in my Ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, controller, action

I'm just learning Ruby on Rails and building a fairly simple app that stores info to a rake generated db. I'm trying to add a new action to the controller but I can't trigger it. There's a `before_action` getting triggered which shouldn't be.

```ruby
class GamesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_entry, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
  end

  def analyse
    #The function here doesnt matter, its not reaching it because its hitting the set_entry instead
    puts 'howdy'
  end
  
  private

    def set_entry
      @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
    end
    
  end
```

The error I'm hitting is `Couldn't find Game with 'id'=analyse"`, highlighting the `set_entry` action, which to my understanding should only be running with the `show`, `edit`, `update`, and `destroy` actions (which are also in the full controller and running fine). There are other actions in the controller (such as `create` and `new`) which don't seem to trigger that `set_entry` and are running just fine as expected. For example, linking to the `new` path takes me to `/entry/new`, while linking to an `edit` path takes me to `/entry/:id/edit`, which is all fine. But it keeps linking my new `analyse` action trying for `entry/:id/analyse` when I want it to go to `entry/analyse`.

My button to trigger it is simply:

```ruby
<%= link_to "Analyse", analyse_path %>
```

Which is in a navbar in my application.html.erb

And here's my routes.rb:

```ruby
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :entry
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
  root to: "entry#index"
  get 'entry/index'
  get 'entry/analyse', as: 'analyse'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The path `/entry/analyse` is matched two routes:

1. `entry#show` action in `resources :entry`
2. `entry#analyse` action in `get 'entry/analyse', as: 'analyse'`

Because the route matching is interpreted through `config/routes.rb` in order, and `resources :entry` is the first route the path is matched. At the result, `entry#show` action will handle the requests from `/entry/analyse`.

The solution is simple, just switch the order of `resources :entry` and `get 'entry/analyse', as: 'analyse'` in `config/routes.rb`. For example:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'entry/analyse', as: 'analyse' # <- to here
  resources :entry
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
  root to: "entry#index"
  get 'entry/index'
  # from here ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks likely. Though I managed to resolve by taking an alternative approach. I created a new analyse controller and put my function in the `analyse#index` of that, then routed there. Your solution looks much neater though, so I shall have to revisit that.

Answer (score 0):

Move all of your `resources` to the end of your route configuration. I am not sure why its getting tripped up but it seems something within your routes is matching analyse to your entry `resource` and routes within rails are matched in order. All custom routes really should come first to prevent something like a generic route catching your expected action.

Best practices also state your `root to:` should be at the top of the configuration since it is your most popular route generally in an application.